# What's up with mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, programming-languages, relational-database

I've seen in a few places on the internet that the future for MySQL is bleak. Mainly people talking poorly about it. Is MySQL really "dying"? If this is the case.. what are good alternatives to database solutions? I work for a small company and we use a lot of MySQL. Is postgre a good solution? What's something that would be useful to learn how to use in the event I go to a larger company? What is the standard corporate database(please don't say oracle)?

Comment: Why do you ask people not to say Oracle? It is widely used.

Comment: Fear! Uncertainty! Doubt!  If I were Oracle, I'd encourage these rumors, too.  Might get you to buy a real Oracle database.   As a matter of practice, it takes a long time for a technology to die.

Comment: Whatever the situation is, there's no reason at all to convert your current databases to something else. MySQL isn't going to just vanish and your databases aren't going to break overnight.

Comment: Considering Facebook is openly using mysql and contributing to it, I doubt these rumors have any validity. Not that I entrust everything that facebook uses and automatically tag it worthwhile, I just put a moderate amount of trust in a technology they deem fit for 500 million users.

Comment: Corporate MySQL might be in trouble but the code is GPL and could fork in an emergency. There is way too much MySQL code around for it not to survive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MySQL is very well established and shows no signs of going anywhere.  People are always predicting this or that will die off, but it's all just a bunch of noise.  Still, I would learn multiple databases as you will be a more well rounded developer.  Knowing Oracle is very valuable on the job market.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry but Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, Postgres are all good databases.  You are asking what will make you marketable and the best way to look at that is to look at what ALL *you* do and how that has to do with databases.  Are you strictly a DBA, then look that up on a jobs site and see how many jobs are for MySQL DBA.  Oracle and SQL Server will probably have more.

Are you a programmer that uses MySQL?  Well, that's different because you should be more database agnostic.  As a programmer you should be able to jump to any database (even language) and learn quickly.

Also, Oracle and SQL Server have free versions you can learn with so you can use them to learn.

As to "larger company," I would suggest looking around at what you consider to be a "larger company" and see what they use.  Where I work we use MySQL, Sql Server, Oracle, and anything that will do the job (sqlite, etc.), but if there was a standard it would be Oracle and SQL Server.

As to your fears - anything can go belly up.  Look at the world's history to see that.  Nothing is certain.  Study broadly.

edit:

That depends on the job description.  You HAVE to do research to see what the market is wanting.  Big big companies like big big money databases (because they are good databases, incidentally).  They just do.  Are there some that like MySQL, sure but not as many, in my opinion.  You must search the market.  That is what everyone does when they are trying to figure out what is needed out there.  You could replace your entire question with a programming language and you'd have the same answer - research.  There are whole sites dedicated to what's hot in the market (don't believe them all btw).  I'm sure MySQL wouldn't hurt but if the job calls for Oracle and you don't know how to even list the tables in Oracle (which is not show tables), then why would they hire you?  But again, depends on what you are doing, just DBA, programmer, what?  You may never have to list the tables if you are a programmer because the DBAs won't let you touch the database.  Research.

Comment: I hate to go here.. but would one want to look at oracle on my resume or mysql on my resume? I know it depends on the job and what I want to do, obviously, but like you said.. what makes a programmer more marketable in the databases? Being able to pick something up is not the question here, its what do companies want to see?

Comment: I think he answers that, if you're marketing yourself as a DBA then you probably want expertise in a couple RDBMSs, but once again it depends what companies you're targetting: web startups gone big are still on MySQL (facebook, yahoo, digg ... http://www.mysql.com/customers/). If you're a programmer the important thing is that you are comfortable with the concepts of a relational database and that you are familiar with SQL syntax, no one really cares which RDBM you were working one before.

Comment: don't put microsoft access on the list!  Well, I guess you can if the job calls for it.

Answer (score -1):

For the future of MySQL I would rather let one of the creators do the talking : http://askmonty.org/w/images/a/a4/Osd2010.pdf

Not to mention that oracle just made InnoDB (a *very* popular MySQL storage engine) commercial only. http://www.cloudave.com/7356/internal-email-on-why-a-software-company-migrates-away-from-mysql/ 
Needless to say it is not going anywhere but it is not *free* to use for sure (never was actually but now oracle will ensure GPL anytime they want). 
After MySQL, PostgreSQL is the most used open source *free* (as in beer) database.

On the commercial (*high cost*) side. Oracle is still the most used database. But it is most certainly an overkill if your software does not need a DBA as a monthly maintenance cost to the customer.

Comment: The link is talking about the MySql Standard edition, enabling you do embed mysql. It doesn't take into account any usage in the free edition. InnoDB wasn't removed from the free version.

Comment: You mean MySQL free edition? That is only for opensource. You cannot make a closed source (free or not free) application with MySQL and not pay oracle : http://www.mysql.com/about/legal/licensing/index.html